Electrons Transferred in an Electrochemical Reation
I was reading Bard's book, I noticed in Chpt 2, he defines the change in Gibbs free energy of a cell as:
$$\Delta G = nFE_{rxn}$$
He describes $n$ as the number of electrons, and $F$ as having units of Coulombs. However, in other sources $F$ has units of C/mol, which makes the most sense to me given that $F = N_A \cdot e $, and $n$ is the number of moles of electrons.
I find this discrepancy confusing as $n$ continues to show as "number of electrons" in other sources and books (Electrochemistry by Hamann).
How can I correctly interpret $n$?

It doesn't really make a difference... And what is the actual question?

My bad, I have updated the question, and added the question. Thanks for the feedback.
It makes a big difference for me on the interpretation of the physical behaviour of the system, are we transferring 3 electrons or 3 moles of electrons, they are significantly different numbers.

No, it's "same difference". 3*96500C = 3 mol * 96500C/mol

I can see it is the same if we consider "n" to be number of moles, as you have done and not the total number of electrons transferred. Which would imply a lot of textbooks have this typo.

ΔG[J/mol]=-n[1].F[C/mol].E [V] // ΔG[J]=-n[mol].F[C/mol].E [V]

@Poutnik, if i consider $\ce{Li^+ + e^- \rightarrow Li^0}$ would the correct interpretation be as follows: For n = 1 e- , then $\Delta G $ with J/mol, means n = 1 mole of electrons per mol of $Li^+$

n moles of electrons is only different from the number of electrons in the same sense that 1 dozen eggs is different to 12 eggs.

Better would be
$$\Delta_r G^{\circ}[\pu{J mol-1}]=-zFE^{\circ}$$
where $z$ is the number of exchanged electrons per a ion.
and
$$\Delta G[\pu{J}]=-nzFE$$
where $n$ is the molar amount of processed ions,
or
$$\Delta G[\pu{J}]=-n_\text{e}FE$$
where $n_\text{e}$ is the molar amount of exchanged electrons.
